# Ethernet suddenly stopped working

Tags: debian, networking, ethernet

After a reboot the ethernet stopped working and the network widget disappeared from the panel. I tried with a live boot of Xubuntu and there was no problem with ethernet. I also rebooted the router.
I run Debian 10 with XFCE.
Here is some output:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 Ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Kernel driver in use: alx
        Kernel modules: alx
```

⠀

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:8a:5b:fb:0b:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:b2:bd:d1:72:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:f9:09:d9:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

⠀

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:8a:5b:fb:0b:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:b2:bd:d1:72:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:f9:09:d9:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

⠀

```
   $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
    # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
    source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
```

EDIT:
After running dhclient -v enp3s0 everything gets back to normal, but I need to run it every time I reboot.
I never manually installed any connection manager.

Other outputs:

```
$ ls /etc/NetworkManager
dispatcher.d  NetworkManager.conf  system-connections
```

⠀

```
$ ls /etc/network/interfaces.d
setup
```

Comment: THere's not a single question mark in the question so... Anyway to troubleshoot I would 1/ disable Docker and prevent it to start at boot (not just stop it) 2/ try as root `dhclient -v enp3s0` just in case

Comment: After running dhclient -v enp3s0  everything get back to normal, but after a reboot I need to run it again.

Comment: Since I don't see any config inside `interfaces` for `enp3s0` you use `NetworkManager` or some other connection manager I presume.  How about checking settings there?

Comment: I never installed any connection manager...

Comment: @LFicess: Edit your original question when giving additional details we ask for in comments, so anyone new reading your question will immediately see it--many here will not read through every comment/reply to find it. What is the contents of the `/etc/network/interfaces.d` directory? Does `/etc/NetworkManager` exist?

Comment: Also, I note that you have both a wired ethernet adapter (enp3s0) and a WiFi adapter (wlp4s0), both of which are in the DOWN state. So the OS _is detecting them_, but something is not triggering to bring either one online.

Comment: I edited the question. Any idea about which could be the problem?